# How can I intercept a transaction in pallet_balance?

Tags: balances, transactions, transfer, pallet-identity

In what way can I intercept a transfer in `pallet_balance`?

For example, I would like to check that the user has an identity in `pallet_identity` before completing a transfer with `pallet_balance`.

Comment: You could implement something like [ensure_signed](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L874) where you also check if an identity exists for that account.

Answer (score 2):

You must create a "wrapper" pallet which will wrap the Balances pallet and expose the APIs you want with the checks you want.

An idea like this was written about here: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/extending-substrate-runtime-modules/

Note it is very old and uses very old syntax, but the ideas are still relevant.

Basically after wrapping your pallet around the Balances pallet, you want to configure your runtime so that the Balances pallet is not callable, and then users can only call APIs through your wrapper pallet with the checks you expect.